# Re-arrange object data in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js

I have one JS object that I need to re-arrange in order to present that data properly in HTML table.

Basically, I need to get few properties from the first row in first object set, and only first property from each other first object rows in each object set. That would be data for first record in newly created object.

```
var testObject =
{
  6:{
    5:{
      0:{ FirstItem: "1-1-1-1", SecondItem: "1-1-1-2", ThirdItem: "1-1-1-3", FourthItem: "1-1-1-4", Year: "2014"},
      1:{ FirstItem: "1-1-2-1", SecondItem: "1-1-2-2", ThirdItem: "1-1-2-3", FourthItem: "1-1-2-4", Year: "2014"},
      2:{ FirstItem: "1-1-3-1", SecondItem: "1-1-3-2", ThirdItem: "1-1-3-3", FourthItem: "1-1-3-4", Year: "2014"}
    },
    10:{
      0:{ FirstItem: "1-2-1-1", SecondItem: "1-2-1-2", ThirdItem: "1-2-1-3", FourthItem: "1-2-1-4", Year: "2014"},
      1:{ FirstItem: "1-2-2-1", SecondItem: "1-2-2-2", ThirdItem: "1-2-2-3", FourthItem: "1-2-2-4", Year: "2014"},
      2:{ FirstItem: "1-2-3-1", SecondItem: "1-2-3-2", ThirdItem: "1-2-3-3", FourthItem: "1-2-3-4", Year: "2014"}
    }
  },
  22:{
    5:{
      0:{ FirstItem: "2-1-1-1", SecondItem: "2-1-1-2", ThirdItem: "2-1-1-3", FourthItem: "2-1-1-4", Year: "2015"},
      1:{ FirstItem: "2-1-2-1", SecondItem: "2-1-2-2", ThirdItem: "2-1-2-3", FourthItem: "2-1-2-4", Year: "2015"},
      2:{ FirstItem: "2-1-3-1", SecondItem: "2-1-3-2", ThirdItem: "2-1-3-3", FourthItem: "2-1-3-4", Year: "2015"}
    },
    10:{
      0:{ FirstItem: "2-2-1-1", SecondItem: "2-2-1-2", ThirdItem: "2-2-1-3", FourthItem: "2-2-1-4", Year: "2015"},
      1:{ FirstItem: "2-2-2-1", SecondItem: "2-2-2-2", ThirdItem: "2-2-2-3", FourthItem: "2-2-2-4", Year: "2015"},
      2:{ FirstItem: "2-2-3-1", SecondItem: "2-2-3-2", ThirdItem: "2-2-3-3", FourthItem: "2-2-3-4", Year: "2015"}
    }
  }
};
```

Desired object:

```
var desiredOutput =
{ FirstItem: "1-1-1-1", FourthItem: "1-1-1-4", Year: "2014", FirstItem: "1-2-1-1", FirstItem: "2-1-1-1", FirstItem: "2-2-1-1" }, 
{ FirstItem: "1-1-2-1", FourthItem: "1-1-2-4", Year: "2014", FirstItem: "1-2-2-1", FirstItem: "2-1-2-1", FirstItem: "2-2-2-1" }, 
{ FirstItem: "1-1-3-1", FourthItem: "1-1-3-4", Year: "2014", FirstItem: "1-2-3-1", FirstItem: "2-1-3-1", FirstItem: "2-2-3-1" };
```

Please check attached image for better understanding.

[image: Curent and desired JS object]

Please check JSFiddle link with object that I currently have and desired output:

https://jsfiddle.net/fn3epjux/1/

I've tried everything, but without success. I'm using underscoreJS in my project.

Comment: Object properties have no defined ordering. If you want an ordering, you should sort the property names yourself (see `Object.keys()`) or else use an array structure in the first place.

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid, an Object can't have more than one key-value pair with the same key.

Comment: @twhb Yes - You are right. I need to update those keys too...